# Непонятная конструкция в JSP JSTL

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

Разбираю пример простой SpringMVC аппликации и возникли трудности с пониманием  [данной конструкции](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/pets/createOrUpdatePetForm.jsp#L22). В частности `pet['new']`. Раньше с ней не сталкивался и объяснения не нашел. Поясните пожалуйста ее логику.
Ссылается вероятно c [этого класса](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/web/PetController.java#L68).